# Browser to webserver communication: Count down page, using JSF

Tags: java, jsf, timer, countdowntimer

newbie here so be easy on me :D

i am ok at java and have written some code that counts down from an input :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Stopwatch {

    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        String secs = sc.nextLine();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer = new Timer();
        interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
        System.out.println(secs);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(setInterval());

            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private static final int setInterval() {
        if (interval == 1) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        return --interval;
    }
}
```

so what ever the user enters, it then counts down every second in the console.

but i am now trying to make a jsf web app that that will have the user enter an input, this value be passed to the java code above, and once the timer is finished, a pop up will appear,

is this something possible to do with JSF ? am i going about this the right way, if not how should i edit my java for this to work

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: This code will execute on the web server, but, you will have to show popup on client's web browser. You will have to maintain the HTTP connection between browser and web server to push the event completion. Otherwise, browser can pull the information periodically from server. Alternatively, you can just implement the countdown timer in javascript which will execute in the brwoser and use some AJAX callback to update the server.

Comment: Thanks, yes i would like this code executing on the server, the reasoning behind this is later on i want to have this count down call another function on the server

Answer (score 0):

Basically, HTTP is a stateless protocol, but, to achieve what you want you will have to keep the **communication open** between browser and server. Not exactly `JSF`, but, you may look at how `Comet` works http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29. You will get an idea how to do this in JSF. Alternatively, if you are using modern browser (HTMl 5 aware) and web server, then have a look at new **WebSocket** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket programming.

Comment: PrimeFaces already has a push component that uses Comet behind the scenes. Sadly, the sample page is unavailable atm.

Comment: Ok thanks i shall take a look at PrimeFaces when it comes online, have i done the java code bit right ? once i can keep the connection open will this work ?

Comment: @user2054949 you can check the sample (when it becomes available) [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf). Otherwise, if you don't want to wait, you can download the showcase and test it yourself.

Comment: It is still down, would you be able to post some sample code to get me started, as this needs to be done soon :)

Comment: @user2054949, you can get the exact same functionality from Richfaces too, [demo here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=poll&skin=blueSky)

Comment: @kolossus that's a polling example, OP's looking for push.

Comment: @user2054949 why are you waiting with your hands tied if **you can download the PrimeFaces showcase and test it by yourself**? Even the message suggest you to do that in order to test the push example.